# Java - sorting a names array to match their scores

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, names

Trying to sort a String array which contains names of participants to match a scores array which holds their scores for a quiz. I've managed to sort the scores from highest to lowest, but the names are in the wrong positions.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is where an `Object` will make your life incredibly easy. Don't handle multiple arrays. Handle a single array of type `Person`.

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int score;

    public Person(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    // you'll need some getters and setters!
}
```

And now you can implement the `Comparable` interface. This allows you to sort. For example..

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>
```

and this will force you to implement the `compareTo` method..

```
public int compareTo(Person other)
{
    if(other.getScore() > this.score) return -1;

    if(other.getScore() < this.score) return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Then, you get to call the `Collections.sort` method to sort it for you..

```
List<Person> myPeople = new ArrayList<Person>(); 

// Populate it..

Collections.sort(myPeople);
```

**Extra Reading**

- Read up on the [Collections class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)).
- Read up on the [Comparable Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).
- Have a read about [Object Oriented Design Principles in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/).

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using objects?

Comment: My point is that doing it without objects will create unmanageable and overly complex code!